# How to draw relative frequency table

Tags: r

```
Src=as.factor(c("nc","us","us","nc","nc","ci","nn","pr","nc","nc","ak","ak","ak","ak","ci","hv","ak","ci","nc","nc"))
Version = as.factor(c(0,4,7,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,0))
table(Src,Version)
```

Output:

```
    Version
Src  0 1 2 4 7 9
  ak 0 5 0 0 0 0
  ci 3 0 0 0 0 0
  hv 0 0 1 0 0 0
  nc 7 0 0 0 0 0
  nn 0 0 0 0 0 1
  pr 1 0 0 0 0 0
  us 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Instead of showing the counted numbers, can I instead show relative frequencies?

Comment: Do you mean like `prop.table(table(Src, Version))`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. You can use `prop.table()` to that effect:

```
prop.table(table(Src, Version))
```

This will produce a table like:

```
    Version
Src     0    1    2    4    7    9
  ak 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  ci 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  hv 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00
  nc 0.35 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  nn 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05
  pr 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  us 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00
```

You can use the optional argument `margin`to request row- or column relative frequencies.

Answer (score 5):

That really is a FAQ.

Just divide your table by its sum :

```
tab <- table(Src,Version)
tab/sum(tab)
```

See also `?prop.table`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `barplot` with `beside=TRUE` to show relative( the plot will not change with proportion options, just the scales) difference between groups.

```
 barplot(table(Src,Version),beside=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: That's quite a literal interpretation of "draw" ;) But, I still think you'd need `barplot(prop.table(table...` to get the output they want....

Comment: @AnandaMahto maybe:) Try to plot the 2 to see difference.. I am really  not very fun of prop.table specially in relative case. And my answer was just an alternative to your first comment that was used as an answer by others...