# For loop in a Matrix - Relative frequency

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to recalculate the relative frequency in a matrix with a For Loop.
I need the sum of each column be one.

I want to divide each value of the matrix by the sum of the colum.

Code:

```
Ej<-matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow=3)
for ( i in 1:ncol(Ej)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(Ej)){
    Ej[i,j]<-Ej[i,j]/sum(Ej[,1])
  }
}
sum(Ej[,1])
```

I want a result like this.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581204/how-to-draw-relative-frequency-table (How to draw relative frequency table).  ```prop.table(Ej, 2)``` does this for you

Answer (score 1):

Using colSums and transpose

```
t(t(Ej) / colSums(Ej))
```

Using apply

```
apply(Ej, 2, function(x) x / sum(x))
```

---

The more apt answer to this question seems to be the one suggested by @ThetaFC:

```
prop.table(Ej, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sweep` here

```
sweep(Ej, 2, colSums(Ej), `/`)

#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.1666667 0.2666667 0.2916667
#[2,] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
#[3,] 0.5000000 0.4000000 0.3750000
```

Although `prop.table` suggested by @ThetaFC is the easiest

```
prop.table(Ej, 2)
```

---

As you can see there are lot of ways in which this can be achieved without `for` loop however, if you still want to use a `for` loop for learning purposes you can do it with single loop over columns

```
for (i in 1:ncol(Ej)) {
    Ej[,i] <- Ej[, i]/sum(Ej[,i])
}
```